# Using a function constructor to add methods to a reference class

Tags: r, google-analytics

I'm trying to simplify the process of creating and submitting queries to the Google Analytics API through [skardhamar's rga](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga). I'm leading a small analytics team which creates reports for clients, and my coworkers are much less comfortable working with scripts and R. As such, I'm trying to provide a few foundational elements and a report template to reduce complexity.

We often run comparisons between sites, so I've created a profile-specific reference class which contains things like the account ID, profile ID, etc. It will come with a small set of predefined query methods, such as the following:

```
profile <- setRefClass("profile",
                       fields = list(
                         accountID = "character",
                         profileID = "character"),
                       methods = list(
                         topPages = function() {
                           ga$getData(profileID,
                                      start.date = helper$start,
                                      end.date = helper$end,
                                      metrics = "ga:pageviews,ga:bounceRate",
                                      dimensions = "ga:pagePath",
                                      sort = "-ga:pageviews")
                         })
                       )
```

I may end up adding a field to store API returns into to limit the number of unnecessary API calls we're making, but that's neither here nor there.

To construct these profile objects, and to add new methods to their reference class, I have a helper reference class:

```
helper <- setRefClass("helper",
                      fields = list(
                        start = "character",
                        end = "character"),
                      methods = list(
                        newMethod = function(name="", metrics="", dimensions="",
                                             sort="") {
                          **take the passed arguments and construct a new 
                          query function**
                          **add function to the profile reference class**
                        },
                        newProfile = function(account="", profile="", name="") {
                          **search for matching account and profile**
                          **create new profile-class object with the passed name**
                        })
                      )
```

Ignoring the potential problems in how I've ordered these examples, is the `helper$newMethod()` I've described even possible?

Comment: If I understand you want to create a method on the fly or dynamically to a class/object from another object? If so , can you please reduce your classes and remove all unnecessary information to put only a small example?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible... when you update the methods of a reference class new objects don't get the updated methods. Also .self is readonly outside of the initialize function so there would be no way to self update.

Comment: Even if I am adding these methods before creating the profile-specific objects? I saw this more as means of insulating my team from the source scripts than to modify the objects on the fly. As such, they would use the method constructor at the head of their document before using `profile$new()`.

Comment: Ahh I must have miss understood your problem slightly. If your newMethod function returns new objects then you could call profile$methods() before profile$new() and the new objects would have the new methods. I thought you wanted to update the methods of the existing object when calling newMethod.

Comment: Oh, no, the method construction would come before any instances of `profile` would be created. How would I go about appending the new constructed method to `profile$methods`?

Answer (score 0):

Does this example get you further to what you need?

```
profile <- setRefClass("profile")
profile$methods(newMethod = function(...) {
  .call <- match.call()
  .call[[1]] <- quote(profile$methods)
  eval(.call)
  profile$new()
})
z <- profile$new()$newMethod(sum=function(x,y){x+y})
z$sum(1,2)
```

Comment: I think—I don't quite follow what's exactly happening inside `profile$methods`, but I'll play around with it. Thanks for the pointers.